# How memory work in assembly 16 bits using DOSBOX

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-16, tasm

I'm trying to understand how memory works in assembly

```
a dd 'aa'
b db 'aaa'
```

this will work just fine and in memory I'll have:
61 61 00 00 61 61 61 ...

but if I to this

```
d dd 'aaa'
```

I get a compilation error saying: 'Value out of range'

Why is that? And if you could get me some documentation or something to understand better it would be nice. Thanks

Comment: What assembler are you using?  It presumably has a manual...

Comment: @NateEldredge : the syntax (no colons) would suggest MASM (or compatible), and I think TASM is the one with a specific error "Value out of Range"

Comment: If you want relatively sane multi-character integer literals and strings, I'd recommend NASM.  [How are dw and dd different from db directives for strings?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38860174) has a NASM answer.

Comment: @MichaelPetch it is from tasm and about compiler i don't know.. It was given to us from college

Comment: It is not obvious here, but note that the endianness messes things up. `dd 'ab'` will actually put `62 61 00 00` into memory which is likely not what you expect. Apparently only `db` supports strings, the others convert it to a 16 bit number for whatever reason.

Comment: @Michael Petch: "the syntax (no colons) would suggest MASM" -- Not true, NASM also allows omitting the colon. This causes a warning if the label is alone on a line, but is otherwise (such as in this example) silently allowed. (I am [trying to add a warning](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392632) for all non-equ labels without colons.)

Comment: @ecm: I said **suggests** (not definitively), but given the use case for no colon favors MASM (or compatible) there was a reasonable chance that's what it was. But among the MASM compatible assemblers ONE in particular has the exact error "Value out of range". As the OP informed us this is in fact TASM.

Answer (score -2):

`dd` stands for "define doubleword". It's for declaring four byte variables. What are you trying to do by placing a two byte text string there?

I'm not sure if placing a *four* byte string under a `dd` will work. At least it would make more sense.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Anyway, two characters work (as shown in the post). 3 or more (including 4) don't.